# Is it a good idea to define properties in Python interfaces?

Tags: python, interface

Is it a good practice to define properties in an interface like this?

```
class MyInterface(object):
    def required_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def required_property(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: I would say, yes. There should be no distinction between proprties or functions. = I know no reason to restrict interfaces to function calls only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a [ABC class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) for that, but yes; you can even use a `@abstractproperty` for that very use-case.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty, abstractmethod

class MyInterface(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def required_method(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def required_property(self):
        pass
```

Subclasses of the ABC are still free to implement `required_property` as an attribute instead; the ABC will only verify the existence of `required_property`, not what type it is.

Comment: Capital suggestion the `ABC class`. It looks redundant at first sight but it revealed mess in my inheritance chain.